# Password manager needed for both MS windows and Chrome book

Tags: password-manager

Is there a password manager that will work off a memory stick with both MS Windows and a chrome book? Some other way to work on both of these two operating systems?

Comment: I guess the obvious choice would be to use some cloud based service which is exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: The obvious answer is [KeePass](https://alternativeto.net/software/keepass/about/).